# How can you toggle other divs separate from each other while on an active div (with JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website in which different layers of `divs` show different sections. Basically it is build up like this:

1. GROUP

   - Multiple options (buttons; select one of the subgroups)
2. SUBGROUP

   - Multiple options (buttons; select one of the subsubgroups)
3. SUBSUBGROUPS
   etc.

Currently I am using JQuery to activate the different `divs`, but I want to navigate between `divs` by clicking outside of them to de-activate or by clicking on another `div`/`button` so it overrules the current active `div`.

Is there a (simple) solution in JQuery and/or CSS to achieve this? I tried multiple things, but everytime wrong `divs` de-activate or pop-up. I think I am missing a mathematical solution here..

I tried using `removeClass` and `addClass`, `toggleClass` or `toggle` in combination with an `.active` class that shows the `div` by using `display:none` and `display:block`. They work when using a few `divs` or just two layers, but when there are multiple layers and combinations I fail in finding the right solution.

```js
// ACTIVATE DIVS
$(document).ready(function() {
  // 1. CONTINENTS
  $(".select-europe").click(function() {
    $("#official_countries").addClass("active");
  });
  // 2. RECOGNIZED STATES
  // 2.EU EUROPE
  $(".select-france").click(function() {
    $("#france-country").addClass("active");
  });
  $(".select-netherlands_the").click(function() {
    $("#netherlands_the-country").addClass("active");
  });
  // 3. STATE
  // 3.EU.FR FRANCE
  $(".select-france-divisions").click(function() {
    $("#france-divisions").addClass("active");
  });
  // 3.EU.NL NETHERLANDS, THE
  $(".select-netherlands_the-divisions").click(function() {
    $("#netherlands_the-divisions").addClass("active");
  });
});

// DE-ACTIVATE DIVS
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  // 1. CONTINENTS
  // 2. RECOGNIZED STATES
  // 2.EU EUROPE
  var $trigger = $(".select-france");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#france-country").removeClass("active");
  }
  var $trigger = $(".select-netherlands_the");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#netherlands_the-country").removeClass("active");
  }
  // 3. STATE
  // 3.EU.FR FRANCE
  var $trigger = $(".select-france-divisions");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#france-divisions").removeClass("active");
  }
  // 3.EU.NL NETHERLANDS, THE
  var $trigger = $(".select-netherlands_the-divisions");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#netherlands_the-divisions").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
#continents {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#official_countries,
#france-country,
#france-divisions,
#netherlands_the-country,
#netherlands_the-divisions {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;

    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#official_countries {
    left: 120px;
    width: calc(100% - 121px);

    background-color: #ccc;
}
#france-country,
#netherlands_the-country {
    left: 240px;
    width: calc(100% - 241px);

    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#france-divisions,
#netherlands_the-divisions {
    left: 360px;
    width: calc(100% - 361px);

    background-color: #999;
}

#official_countries.active,
#netherlands_the-country.active,
#france-country.active,
#france-divisions.active,
#netherlands_the-divisions.active {
  display: block;
}

.select-country {
  display: block;
}
.section {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="continents">
  <button class="select-europe">Europe</button>
</div>
<div id="official_countries">
  <div class="overview">
    <button class="select-country select-france">France</button>
    <button class="select-country select-netherlands_the">Netherlands, the</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="france-country">
  <header>French Republic</header>
  <div class="overview">
    <div class="section">
      <button class="select-france-divisions">France</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="netherlands_the-country">
  <button class="select-netherlands_the-divisions">Netherlands, the</button>
</div>
<div id="france-divisions"></div>
<div id="netherlands_the-divisions"></div>
```

I expected every previous `div`—that activated the `div` above it—would close again when clicking outside the `div` above. But in between `divs` disappear when clicking on other `divs` underneath or above it.

Comment: Please provide an example that matches what you say is happening. When I click on `Europe` in what you have currently shown, then `France` and `Netherlands, the` show up, but that’s it - there doesn’t appear to be _anything_ else happening no matter where and what I click afterwards.

Comment: And it would probably make more sense, if your HTML structure was matching your data structure to begin with. Instead of divs that are floating in space as siblings, this should rather be a nested structure to begin with.

Comment: @04FS In some sort of strange way it works in my browser and not in this snippet, I am diving into it now. And a nested structure sounds absolutely like a good solution, do you have any examples or links that I could possibly look at? Thanks so far for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would of course have to adapt the styles and html to your needs:

```js
$('li').on("click", function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 let $el = $(this);
  if(!$el.children('ul').hasClass('active')) {
   $('#tree').find('ul').removeClass('active');
   $el.parentsUntil('#tree').addClass('active');
  }
  $el.children('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}

#tree {
  display:block;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree">
  <li>EU
    <ul>
      <li>FR
        <ul>
          <li>Division 1</li>
          <li>Division 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>NL
        <ul>
          <li>Division 1</li>
          <li>Division 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>US
    <ul>
        <li>TX
          <ul>
            <li>Division 1</li>
            <li>Division 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>NY
          <ul>
            <li>Division 1</li>
            <li>Division 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's great, I love the simple nesting in this solution. Probably with a `position: fixed;` the different lists could all be aligned at the top of the page right? I think this is the best answer, thanks man. Really appreciate it!
I tried to implement it in my code but it wasn't working, don't know what I am doing wrong but I'll try to fix it.

Comment: check this fiddle for an example of positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/b7a629xu/23/ glad i could help